# Embed mixpanel script in an angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mixpanel

I'm trying to implement mixpanel in an angular app but I do not want to embed the mixpanel script in my html, I'd rather have it in my index.run.js file which contains most of my configurations. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, I just added the mixpanel script in my `index.run.js` file in between

```
 // jscs:disable
 /* jshint ignore:start */

 // mixpanel script

 /* jshint ignore:end */
 // jscs:enable
```

That's all :)